# jCarousel vertical and horizontal photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, jcarousel

Here is my website

```
http://81.198.86.35:8084/nv/course/10/
```

I have vertical and horizontal photos. I need different width, but jCarousel makes all widths the same. How to make different widths?

Comment: check this out will help u..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245595/how-do-i-change-image-width-in-jcarousel

Comment: No, i can change the width of the picture, but <li> is expanded and i can not do anything with that.